# How to use laravel file manager by unisharp on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, unisharp-file-manager

First I will tell you that I have made this on my localhost and works well. But when I use on the production server(shared hosting) it does not work. 
when I access my web it shows :
Class 'UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm' not found

I put this on my route/web.php :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'verified']], function () {
  Route::group(['prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager', 'middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    \UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm::routes();
  });
});
```

I have run all commands from the documentation, and also upload all necessary files that produced by the commands. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you upload your `vendor` directory or did you run `composer install` on the remote site?

Comment: i've done it man

Comment: I don't know what happened, but now it works, I did not change anything :)

Comment: @Farhan, then your `config` had cleared. That's why its working now.